# Puppet, wget and proxy

Tags: linux, proxy, puppet

I am trying to setup a proxy before the wget call is issued:

```
file { "/etc/environment":
    content => inline_template("
        http_proxy=http://10.0.12.13:8080
        https_proxy=http://10.0.12.13:8080")
}
```

The problem is that I have to restart the Puppet's session in order to load the environment properly.

I have also tried to export the variables in the exec statement:

```
exec { "proxy-export-vars":
    provider => "shell",
    command => "export http_proxy=http://10.0.12.13:8080 && export https_proxy=http://10.0.12.13:8080",
}
```

The question is - how to load the environment settings without restarting the session and the puppet apply process?

## Update

The [WGET puppet plugin](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/maestrodev/wget) is using [the top scope variables](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_scope.html#accessing-out-of-scope-variables) searching for proxy settings. So the trick is to define these variables in [the top scope](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_scope.html#accessing-out-of-scope-variables), that is before the node definition. The complete working code:

```
$http_proxy = "http://10.0.12.13:8080"
$https_proxy = "http://10.0.12.13:8080"

node 'machine' {

    # ...
}
```

And from now on the [WGET puppet plugin](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/maestrodev/wget) is going to fetch resources with these proxy settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to set an environment variable for a single `exec` resource is to use the `environment` attribute.  See the documentation [here](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#exec-attributes).  For example:

```
exec {'fetch something':
  environment => [
    'http_proxy=http://10.0.12.13:8080',
    'https_proxy=http://10.0.12.13:8080',
  ],
  command => '/usr/bin/wget -o /tmp/myfile http://myserver/myfile',
}
```

Your second attempt...

```
exec { "proxy-export-vars":
    provider => "shell",
    command => "export http_proxy=http://10.0.12.13:8080 && export https_proxy=http://10.0.12.13:8080",
```

...would fail because (a) `export` is a shell built-in command, so
Puppet wouldn't be able to `exec` it since there is no corresponding
binary...and (b) even if it could, it wouldn't do what you want, because
setting an environment variable like that is not persistent -- it only
affects the current process and its children.

Comment: `export` may even work with `provider => shell` but your second point holds - the shell which exports those values will terminate promptly.

Comment: Totally missed the fact that `provider` was in there.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: That's no good since the WGET is used via wget plugin a couple of times by other modules installing some software. I would have to setup the proxy for each command. But you've pointed me to some direction - I would try to find out whether the plugin can be modified in order to set proxy before each fetch.

Comment: Found the solution using your tips. My question is now updated with the full working solution. Thanks!